# Como fechar modal ao clicar no X?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma *modal* que abre quando o mouse sai da pagina. O problema é que quando eu tento fechar no `X`, ela não fecha:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onmouseleave="Open('openModal')">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


 <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" >
     <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" onclick="close('openModal')" 
 class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>1 paragrafo.</p>
        <p>teste teste teste  teste teste teste v</p>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
    function Open(x) {
        x = document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "1";

    }
    function close(x){
        y = document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "0";
    }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faltou postar o código JavaScript que abre sua modal... @questão: Já tentou adicionar um evento `mouseout` em cima do `body`?

Comment: Ainda não tenho, pois não tenho ideá de como fazer, sou iniciante, ainda tenho dificuldade

Comment: @LipESprY Não, vou tentar

Comment: "*- eu consigo abrir com um link*" O link "puro" não abre o modal. Ele apenas "rola" a página até onde está o objeto ancorado via `id`. [Edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/355009/edit) aí e posta sua página completa em um *snippet*. Dado o seu nível como iniciante, talvez o código esteja lá e você não sabe. ;D

Comment: @LipESprY Vlw pela dica! Vou alterar

Comment: Não, colega! kkkkk! Snippet é onde você vai colar o código fonte da sua página com o modal... Veja nessa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO2vE.png No caso, você posta TODO o código. Se necessário, eu ou outro colega editamos sua pergunta removendo oq não for necessário. ;D

Comment: @LipESprY Fiz algumas alterações

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vê se é disso que precisa:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onmouseleave="abreModal()">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abreModal() {
            document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "1";
            document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "block";

        }
        function fechaModal(){
            document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "0";
            document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
         <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" onclick="fechaModal();" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Modal Box</h2>
            <p>1 paragrafo.</p>
            <p>teste teste teste  teste teste teste v</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

O problema do seu código foi utilizar o nome `close` na sua função. Existe um método com este mesmo nome. Veja mais em:

> [Window close() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)

Repare que renomeei as suas funções, tirei os parâmetros desnecessários e reorganizei seu código... Inclusive carregar as funções **antes do carregamento da página em si**.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: @AndreFirmo É bom que, a partir de agora, você não vai mais colocar nomes comuns nas suas funções, como `open()`, `close()`, `run()`, `get()`, etc... ;D

Comment: pode deixar @LipESprY