# Como esconder um elemento com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, atributos, click

Tenho uma div que serve como caixa de alerta. Nela tenho um texto e um botão.
Preciso que toda a caixa (a div no caso) fique invisível quando o botão for clicado, mas não consegui fazer isso funcionar de jeito nenhum.

```html
<div class="allert-box" id="hm-tools-alert">
                <p>
                    Texto
                </p>
                <button class="allert-box-close" id="hm-tools-alert-close">
                    <img src="images/icons/close.png" alt="Fechar">
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como fechar modal ao clicar no X?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355009/como-fechar-modal-ao-clicar-no-x)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É possível fazer isso com um onclick simples no botão:

```css
.allert-box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: teal;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="allert-box" id="hm-tools-alert">
    <p>
        Texto
    </p>
    <button class="allert-box-close" id="hm-tools-alert-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';">FECHAR</button>
</div>
```